# insert and display data on a dashboard for currently (logged in)user using PHP, MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a user_login table, having pk = userid.
A credit_request table is created which references to userid as fk.
when the user login, he should see only his entries in the dashboard.
But, here i am not able to insert data, once i link a foreign key to it.
and even the data inserted through phpmyadmin is visible to all users.

Please help me out.
how to insert and retrieve data for logged in users.

<>

//Database setup for Credit request

//Insert data into Credit request

```
if(isset($_POST['taskid']))
{

    $taskid =$_POST['taskid'];
    $orderid = $_POST['orderid'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $query1 = "INSERT INTO credit_request(taskid, orderid, status)
    VALUES ('$taskid', '$orderid', '$status')";

    if ($connect->query($query1) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $query1 . "<br>" . $connect->error;
    }


}

//Display data for credit request

$query2 = "SELECT taskid, orderid, status FROM credit_request WHERE agentid = '$userid'";
$res = $connect->query($query2);


if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br>taskid: " . $row["taskid"]. " -orderid: " . $row["orderid"]. " --:" . $row["status"]."";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: I am not able to insert data into the table           Error: "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`login`.`credit_request`, CONSTRAINT `credit_request_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`agentid`) REFERENCES `user_login` (`userid`))"

Comment: May be you are trying to insert a row into `credit_request` which can't refer to `userid` of `user_login`,i.e,`userid` doesn't exist.Check again with DB.

Comment: the same sql query is working well in phpmyadmin, but it shows error while i insert the data through dashboard

Comment: plesae check the link (i have attached image showing the relationship between table, here i dont have reputation to add images):  "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184439/store-and-display-data-to-the-particular-user-who-has-logged-in"

Comment: where you are inserting fk(userid) in credit_request table ?

Comment: I am not inserting fk into credit_request table, but i am not able to insert any data into the table. code: "$query1 = "INSERT INTO credit_request(taskid, orderid, status)
    VALUES ('$taskid', '$orderid', '$status')";"

Comment: It's important to insert user_id in credit request table..

Comment: @prerana your credit_request table has userid as fk , so you need to insert that, else how will you refer relationship

Comment: once the user login, he must see his information in the dashboard. and again he needs to insert data(taskid, orderid, status) into credit_request table. whtever we insert, it must display in the agents dashboard, i cannot insert fk(userid) there, it should automatically get updated. please help me out in this

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem on update, on delete when creating foreign key..

Here's an example of how you'd build your schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `state_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `country_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) 
   REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='';

INSERT INTO country (country_name) VALUES ('US of A');

INSERT INTO state_table (state_name,country_id) VALUES
('Minnesota', 2),
('Arizona', 2);
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6782/2) for more.

Comment: I check the above link, and created a table with fk as given there, but still i am not able to insert data into the table, i am getting the same error